# Is it possible to call one controller from another controller without redirecting as means to augment Secure.login()?

Tags: authentication, playframework

I'm using the Play Secure module and I would like to set the flash param 'url' to the value of the http referer header, if url is not already set, before `Secure.login()` executes so that upon success the browser is redirected back to the page that originally called login. Essentially defining a sensible default.

Ideally there would be a call back in `Secure.login()` that calls a method in a custom Security class (e.g. `Security.onLogin()`) where this logic could be placed. Unfortunately this callback doesn't currently exist so a work around that I'm considering is to intercept the `/login` request before it is passed to `Secure.login()` through a route mapping declared before the Secure route mapping. Then execute the code to set the flash param to the referer header and then call `Secure.login()` and continue on as normal. However I don't want my controller action handler to 'redirect' to `Secure.login()` just forward. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure module is a tiny module. Just copy the code from the Secure module into your app instead of dependeing of it and adapt the code to your needs.

Comment: Yes that was next on my list if there was no quick work around. Just wanted to avoid having to maintain any more code but as you say it's not big. thx